# Unable to get an attribute value of an Object returned by Serverside controller in Lightning

Tags: lightning

I have a server side controller:

```
public with sharing class DynamicRowController {

    public class ModelWrapper {

        public Set<String> variantSet{get; set;}
        public Set<String> extColorSet{get; set;}
        public Set<String> intColorSet{get; set;}

        public ModelWrapper () {

        }
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static ModelWrapper fetchModelDetails (String strModel) {

        ModelWrapper objWrapper = new ModelWrapper();

        objWrapper.variantSet  = new Set<String>();
        objWrapper.extColorSet = new Set<String>();
        objWrapper.intColorSet = new Set<String>();

        try {
            List<VW_Price__c> lstModelDetails = [SELECT Id, VW_GradeCode__c, VW_ColorCode__c, VW_Type__c
                                                 FROM   VW_Price__c
                                                 WHERE  VW_ModelGroupCode__c =:strModel];

            for (VW_Price__c vp : lstModelDetails) {
                if (vp.VW_GradeCode__c != NULL) {
                    objWrapper.variantSet.add(vp.VW_GradeCode__c);
                }
                if (vp.VW_ColorCode__c != NULL) {
                    if (vp.VW_Type__c != NULL && vp.VW_Type__c == 'CE') {
                        objWrapper.extColorSet.add(vp.VW_ColorCode__c);
                    }
                    else if (vp.VW_Type__c != NULL && vp.VW_Type__c == 'CI') {
                        objWrapper.intColorSet.add(vp.VW_ColorCode__c);
                    }
                }
            }

            return objWrapper;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            system.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, e.getCause() + ':: ' + e.getLineNumber() + ':: ' + e.getMessage());
            return objWrapper;
        }
    }
}
```

The js controller calls the above controller like following:

```
getModelDetails : function (component, event) {
    var model   = event.getSource().get("v.value");
    var action  = component.get("c.fetchModelDetails");
    action.setParams({
        strModel : model
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function (response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var modelDetails   = component.get("v.ModelInstance");
            var existingModels = response.getReturnValue();
            console.log(existingModels.variantSet);

            modelDetails.VW_Variant__c   = existingModels.variantSet;
            modelDetails.VW_ExtColour__c = existingModels.extColorSet;
            modelDetails.VW_IntColor__c  = existingModels.intColorSet;

            component.set("v.ModelInstance", modelDetails);
        }
        else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
            console.log("Response is Incomplete!!");
        }
        else if (state === "ERROR") {
            var errors = response.getError();
            if (errors) {
                if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                    console.log("Error:: " + errors[0].message);
                }
            }
        }   else {
            console.log("Unknown Error!!");
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

The following line gives output "undefined". However I want to get a list of value.

```
console.log(existingModels.variantSet);
```

This is occurring due to some conceptual problem. Please tell me what could be the workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is that for properties of a wrapper class to be serialized back to the client side they need to be marked as [@AuraEnabled](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex_auraenabled_annotation.htm):

```
public class ModelWrapper {
    @AuraEnabled public Set<String> variantSet{get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled public Set<String> extColorSet{get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled public Set<String> intColorSet{get; set;}
}
```

FYI, this:

```
    catch (Exception e) {
        system.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, e.getCause() + ':: ' + e.getLineNumber() + ':: ' + e.getMessage());
        return objWrapper;
    }
```

is not a good idea as in production it would result in a "silent failure" that could be hard to diagnose. Best remove the try/catch or also pass the error back to the client so people know it is going wrong:

```
    catch (Exception e) {
        String message = e.getCause() + ':: ' + e.getLineNumber() + ':: ' + e.getMessage();
        system.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, message);
        throw new AuraHandledException(message);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Keith. Thank you very much for the response. I have got my issue resolved. Thanks too for the suggestion regarding catch block!!

Comment: @JyotirmayPaul No problem. This is not well emphasised in the documentation for properties: a lot of the docs talk more about methods.